# Can't print file after writing to it

Tags: ruby, io

For some reason I cannot get this to print anything with the final line.

```
prev_std = STDOUT

$stdout = File.open(reportname, 'w')

# Several things happen to print to STDOUT here

$stdout = STDOUT

# Tell them that the report was written
puts "Report written to #{ reportname }"

# Slurp in the report ( FIXME )
reporttext = File.open(reportname, 'r') { |f| f.read }

# Print out the report after ( FIXME )
puts reporttext
```

I've just written the report to the file, but somehow I can't read it back to the screen. I'm using the exact same string in the code to refer to the file in both cases. Checking at the shell prompt proves the file was written correctly, and yet I still can't get it to print to the screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue comes from the file not being closed. Changing `$stdout` doesn't close the file object it used to refer to. Add `$stdout.close` to the line before you reassign it to the old stdout.